# Is Deep SARSA learning a feasible approach?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, off-policy-methods, sarsa

I noticed that SARSA has been rarely used in the deep RL setting. Usually, the training for DQN is done off-policy. I think one of the major reasons for this is due to greater sample efficiency in training due to the reuse of experiences in training off-policy. For SARSA, I would think that at every time step of an update, a stochastic gradient update of that sample would have to be performed and then the sample would have to be thrown away.

The approach while might take longer to train, might still allow the agent to do relatively well. Would deep SARSA implementation perform as well as DQN in terms of final performance (since SARSA would definitely take longer to train)?